# Music Library using java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, database-design, relational-database

Please refer me a good structure for MySQL table for a music library. I suggest fields song name, song artist,album.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to start with [database answers](http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/).  This is a large collection of database models, offered for free.  Many of them have no implementation alonmg with them, so they are just a starting point for a do it yourself project.  But the author has done a lot of work clarifying the problem.

I don't know about music libraries specifically, but you should be able to find them if they are there.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the solution under library tab on the website link you posted. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to make it a relational database you'll want to have at least an artist (or band) table, song table, and album table.

An artist/band can have many albums so have a foreign key in the album table.  A song can be a single or part of album, so you could put a foreign key in the song table that could link to an album.  Also maybe you'll want a flag in the song table that would say whether it's a single or part of an album.